# Cant write data to database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have spent hours of troubleshooting trying to find the error but I, for the life of me, can not find it.

I am trying to insert data into my mysql database and it will not work.
I get no error, and dont know how I would modify my code to get one.

This is my **PHP code**:

```
// write new users data into database
$query_new_user_insert = $this->db_connection->prepare('INSERT INTO users (user_name, user_first, user_last, user_icon, user_password_hash, user_email, user_activation_hash, user_registration_ip, user_registration_datetime) VALUES(:user_name, :user_first, :user_last, :user_icon, :user_password_hash, :user_email, :user_activation_hash, :user_registration_ip, now())');
$query_new_user_insert->bindValue(':user_name', $user_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query_new_user_insert->bindValue(':user_first', $user_first, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query_new_user_insert->bindValue(':user_last', $user_last, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query_new_user_insert->bindValue(':user_icon', $user_icon, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query_new_user_insert->bindValue(':user_password_hash', $user_password_hash, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query_new_user_insert->bindValue(':user_email', $user_email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query_new_user_insert->bindValue(':user_activation_hash', $user_activation_hash, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query_new_user_insert->bindValue(':user_registration_ip', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query_new_user_insert->execute();
```

When I executed the above code, getting this error:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string '00000' (length=5)
  1 => null
  2 => null
```

What's the error mean and how can I fix it?

I'm not sure what else you would need for code so if there is another portion you want, let me know.

Comment: what type of error you get?

Comment: whats the error? we don't know tell us. just turn on error reporting

Comment: How would I turn on error reporting? I've received errors for other things but none on this. @Ghost

Comment: Add `var_dump($this->db_connection->errorInfo());` after `execute()` to check for errors. By the way, there's no need to be that verbose, try using question mark placeholders.

Comment: @renocor Thank you, I added var_dump to the end and got a error. I put it in the question? What the hell does it mean?

Comment: The `00000` usually means successful, so that is strange that you have that and it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the problem. My sql database didn't have default values for the rows that weren't being submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following line of code

```
define("HASH_COST_FACTOR", "10");
```

To support the code

```
$hash_cost_factor = (defined('HASH_COST_FACTOR') ? HASH_COST_FACTOR : null);
```